# how i get diff value in particular text box

Tags: php, ajax

i get all ajax value in all textbox field.. how cann i get particular value in paricular field..plz help me how i can get location in location field,machin_no in machin_no field and etc..i send below code for this issue...

```
function getuserName(strURL)
{   

    var req = getXMLHTTP();     
    if (req) 
    {
        //function to be called when state is changed
        req.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            //when state is completed i.e 4
            if (req.readyState == 4) 
            {           
                // only if http status is "OK"
                if (req.status == 200)
                {   

                        document.getElementById('location').value=req.responseText;
                        document.getElementById('msrno').value=req.responseText;                        
                        document.getElementById('cust_no').value=req.responseText;                      
                    //var name = document.getElementById('location').value=req.responseText;                        


                } 
                else 
                {
                    alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                }
            }               
         }          
         req.open("GET", strURL, true);
         req.send(null);
    }           
}
</script>



</head>
<body>
<div id="content" class="regtitle">

      <div id="regform">
        <form name="formreg">
            <div id="rowone">
                <label>Customer Name</label> <input name="custname" id="custname" type="text"  placeholder="Customer Name" onkeydown="getuserName('getdata.php?custname='+this.value)"/>
                <label>Current Locaiton</label> <input name="location" id="location" type="text" placeholder="Current Location" />
            </div>

            <div id="rowtwo">
            <span><label>Machine Sr. No.</label> <input name="msrno" id="msrno" type="text" placeholder="Machine Sr. No."/></span>

            <span id="custno"><label>Customer No.</label><input name="custno" id="cust_no" type="text" placeholder="Customer No." />
            </span>`enter code here`
```

Comment: You have to show example response.

Comment: what format is the response? plain text? html? json? integers?

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery to put a value inside of a field is as follows. You can also set a variable to equal the element's field value.

```
$('#location').val() = 'Your location string, or variable';
```